# Content Flash in Protected Route with Preact HOC

Tags: typescript, auth0, preact

I am experimenting with Auth0 and Preact and TypeScript and have created a Protected Route HOC that gets a token asynchronously from Auth0 using a requested permission (Scope). If the token is successful, then it renders the view, or it will redirect to the login view if the user is not authenticated or it will show an access denied message if the user does not have the appropriate permission.

I am experiencing a loading flash on the page while the token is obtained asynchronously from Auth0. This also means the entire DOM gets re-rendered every time so it looks more like a traditional web app where the entire page is loaded each time.

I’m not sure how to prevent this content flash while the token is obtained. Is there a better way to be implementing this protected route?

```
import { FunctionComponent, h } from "preact";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import { useLocation } from "preact-iso";
import routeHelper from "../../components/routeHelper";
import { useEffect, useState } from "preact/hooks";
import { audience, connection, scopes } from "../../components/authorisation";

type Props = {
    scope: string;
    component: FunctionComponent<any>;
};

const ProtectedRoute: FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => {
    const { loginWithRedirect, isLoading, isAuthenticated, getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
    const location = useLocation();
    const [scope, setScope] = useState("");
    
    const loading = <div class="p-2 text-center">Loading...</div>;

    const login = () => {
        loginWithRedirect({
            authorizationParams: {
                connection,
                scope
            },
            appState: {
                returnTo: window.location.href
            },
        });
    };

    const checkAccess = async () => {
        try {
            await getAccessTokenSilently({
                authorizationParams: {
                    audience,
                    scope: props.scope
                }
            });
            setScope(props.scope);
        } catch (error) {
            const message = (error as Error).message;
            if (message == "Login required") {
                login();
            } else {
                location.route(routeHelper.accessDenied);
            }
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        checkAccess();
    }, [getAccessTokenSilently, props.scope]);

    
    if (isLoading || !isAuthenticated || !scope) {
        return loading;
    }

    return h(props.component, props);
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Comment: It should usually be fine to remove that `loading` value and always render the route -- if the user is unauthenticated, they can be routed away pretty quickly. Using `loading` like that (as well as suspense fallbacks) will thrash the DOM pretty badly, as you're essentially blowing away the entire tree on nav, then recreating it (or the login page). It's not a good pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I changed the code to only show the loading message when isLoading || !isAuthenticated from the call to useAuth0() as I know this is where the longer wait occurs on first initialisation/login via Auth0. Otherwise, I just render the view and it has eliminated the flash on subsequent visits to those views.